# SQL: issues Multiple Date formats same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I get a dump of data in Excel, dates in the source system are not consistent (Same Column - Varchar)

**Dates**
YYYY-MM-DD , MM/YYYY, DD/MM/YYYY

2023-10-15
09/2025
05/12/2026

**Question**
Anybody have any suggestions on how to convert all these to a consistent format i.e. YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: There isn't one, if I am honest. What "date" is `09/2025`? It doesn't have a day part, so is it the 1st? Perhaps the 31st? Is it actually a date range (SQL Server doesn't support there) or perhaps is it actually the 9th day of 2025? What date is `05/06/2025`? Is it 05 June 2025 or 06 May 2025? How do you know? Could you have really awful dates like `01/02/03`?

Comment: The real solution is fix your storage or input process so that the dates are stored as dates, not a text value that could be *any* format. Likely a lot of data you have right now you will be unable to tell what its true value is, and thus is meaningless and should be assumed to be unknown.

Comment: If your dates have no date assigned then no. how would that even be possible?.. 
Having different formated could be fine as long as you handle each format differently and hope the users won't come up with new formats. such as 2022_02_02

Comment: Thanks , I came to the same conclusion ; the system this company designed is one of the worst I have seen , just wanted to double check if anything I can do

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the field to a Datetime value:

```
CAST(EndDate AS Datetime)
```

But if you encounter a row with data that the CAST cannot automatically covert then you'll get an error. You can resolve this by doing the following:

```
CASE
WHEN TRY_CAST(EndDate as Datetime) IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(EndDate AS Datetime)
ELSE [Insert code to handle anything that CAST can't.]
END
```

Comment: You can remove the case and just use `isnull`

Comment: @Stu You can, but you might run into some limitations with the types of expressions you can use as the replacement_value for ISNULL(), and it'll be much harder to read if your expression is anything other than very simple. Unless there is a significant performance difference I always aim for the most readable code possible.